# push message in to MQ from WSO2 ESB

Tags: wso2, jms, esb, mq, messagebroker

I am new to ESB and JMS, I need to pull a message from MQ, transform the same in ESB and push the resultant message in to another MQ from ESB.

I tried the below document, https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB490/ESB+as+Both+a+JMS+Producer+and+Consumer

I created a proxy service in ESB, which listens to a MQ in wso2 message broker. So if I post a message into that MQ it is pulled by ESB. I am not able to proceed after this point.

Can you give some leads on how to transform message (binary to TLV) and push into another MQ?

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please review the help (top of the page next to the search box) for what questions are on topic for the site. I've voted to close this as being too broad.  The question could be improved by including code, pasting in the errors (or stating that there are no errors seen), including logs, etc.  You can edit your own questions even with only one reputation, just click "edit" below the question.  If the question is not improved, a few more close votes would delete it before too long.  Good luck!

Comment: can you provide us with the proxy xml config?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It worked now!!